# Send a string to the server controller using http.get - ASP.NET MVC

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I'm new to mvc and I want to send a get request with a parameter, however the parameter on the server side is always null.
On the client side I do the following request using angular in a js file:

```
$http.get('api/person/getPersons', "TEST");
```

My PersonController has the following method:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Get all persons from the database.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>All persons.</returns>
    [HttpGet]
    [ActionName("getPersons")]
    public IHttpActionResult GetPersons(string personToFind)
    {
        return this.Content(HttpStatusCode.OK, personToFind);
    }
```

In this case the string stays null, also tried the following two options but neither of them worked.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Get all persons from the database.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>All persons.</returns>
    [HttpGet]
    [ActionName("getPersons")]
    public IHttpActionResult GetPersons([FromBody] string personToFind)
    {
        return this.Content(HttpStatusCode.OK, personToFind);
    }
```

.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Get all persons from the database.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>All persons.</returns>
    [HttpGet]
    [ActionName("getPersons")]
    public IHttpActionResult GetPersons([FromUri] string personToFind)
    {
        return this.Content(HttpStatusCode.OK, personToFind);
    }
```

I also tried to make an object from 'personToFind' but that gives me an empty System.object.

I would be very happy if someone knows what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `$http.get('api/person/getPersons?personToFind=TEST")` with `[FromUri]` kind.

`$http.get('api/person/getPersons?personToFind=' + encodeURIComponent("TEST"))` to be on safer side if search term contains special chars.